# Starlette CORSMiddleware not setting cookies in browsers, only in Postman

Tags: cookies, fastapi, starlette

```
import random
from typing import Any
import uuid
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Request
from pydantic import BaseModel
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

from db import Session, Statement, User, Vote

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/set/{item}")
async def set(request: Request, item:str):
    request.session["item"] = item
    return request.session["item"]

@app.middleware("http")
async def process_auth(request: Request, call_next):
    print(f"Processing auth in session. Session: {request.session}")
    response = await call_next(request)
    return response


app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=[
        "http://localhost:3000",
        "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
    ],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key="some-random-string")
```

I am trying to use Starlette's CORSMiddleware but it's not setting the cookie inside browsers when making a request to `/set` from http://localhost:3000, only when doing the same in Postman. I have checked both inside `request.session` and in the Cookies tab of the browsers. Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: Added withCredentials in axios but still same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Switched to making requests to the local server via localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 and it worked. For some reason, the browser thinks those are two different domains.